# Kdenlive, how to use the chromakey effect properly?

Tags: video-editor, kdenlive

I put the video with the greenscreen onto the top, 
below is the clip, which is intended to shine through 
the green.

So, I right click onto the top clip, select chomakey among effects, 
use the color picker to select the green and adjust the variance.

However, to my surprise, the green of the top clip does not become
transparent, but everything else.

[image]

Comment: https://forum.kde.org/viewforum.php?f=262 I don't think this question is relevant here, it's true that your'e running Kdenlive on Ubuntu but the question is fully about Kdenlive, please ask it here you'll surely get some response

Comment: I understand your point, I thought maybe I can ask this because there is a kdenlive tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) - Right-click your top clip(green screen clip), go to "Add Transition" and select "Composite". This will show up between your clips.

2) - Extend "composite" to the same length as your clips.

3) - Right-click your top clip again, go to "Add Effect" and select "Chroma Key".

4) - When changing the color, manually open the color picker and choose your color instead of using the water droplet tool at the side.

5) - Right-click the next clip to be shown, go to "Crop and transform and select "Crop, Scale & Tilt" to adjust the clip to be shown if necessary.

Comment: wow, this worked perfect,  point 4 was the key, I did not realize there are two color pickers. only point 5 i do not understand

Answer (score 0):

Really, that behaviour is if you use the GPU chroma key. If you use the CPU version you will get the blue/green background transparent after selected the matching color with the pipe.

PS: You will get the background transparent, so no need of composite transition after the chroma, simply put the new background video/still in the track under the one you chroma keyed :D

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is what was already suggested in the accepted answer!

Comment: was suggested to use a composite transition ... no needed if cpu chroma key